# How can I use Google Drive on Ubuntu phone

Tags: phone, drive, google

I have the Google Drive app installed on my Ubuntu phone.

I also have photos on my phone.

How can I load these photos onto Google Drive ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a webapp. You will have to select in it to upload files, and then I think, select the photos individually from the content picker, to be able to upload them. It is the same as if you were using the https://drive.google.com/ site in a browser.